# How to remove border line in my website overlaping my sidebar border

Tags: html, web, blogger

Hi I have a blog site http://raywiliamjohnson.blogspot.com blogger blog. It's a customized template in blogger, therefore I cannot edit it using the blogger design customization tool. I'm having a hard-time determining which line of code is responsible in displaying the 2 side grey border line in my site. Its overlapping on my sidebar border . how could I remove or adjust it? Pls check my source code and suggest me what to do . thanks

Comment: You should add a picture displaying the border lines. I's hard to guess which borders you mean.

Comment: here is the image of the border line I want to remove http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-kLZ4uq4PjnM/T5sUhb1KknI/AAAAAAAAAtY/5AxqFPepC4M/s1600/Capture.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the 2 gray borderds on the left and right, then it is caused by this:

```
body {
  background: #F7F7F7 url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nVwJ4zhT3Fs/TsYD0lnPFXI/AAAAAAAACqc/YxEOj7__SyM/s000/bg.gif) repeat-y top center;
}
```

switching that of did remove them

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering the width of the content-wrapper div so that it fits in those borders and then play with the dimensions of the divs that are contained in the content-wrapper so that it doesn't look like a mess.

Comment: I really want those border's be removed . Anyway thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

On line 33 of your blog's source, you will see this inline CSS:

```
body{background:#f7f7f7 url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nVwJ4zhT3Fs/TsYD0lnPFXI/AAAAAAAACqc/YxEOj7__SyM/s000/bg.gif) repeat-y top center; margin:0; color:#333; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-align:center}
```

Remove the `background` selector:

```
body{margin:0; color:#333; font-family:arial; font-size:12px; text-align:center}
```

It is the background image which is responsible for it.